# join() is not a function javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function dnaTransform(str) {
  const pairs = {
    A: "T",
    T: "A",
    G: "C",
    C: "G"
  }
  return str.split('').map(function(item) {
    var result = pairs[item].join()
    return result
  })
}

console.log(dnaTransform("ATTGC"))
```

Why does it say:

> "Uncaught TypeError: pairs[item].join is not a function"?

Why can't `join()` be used here?

Comment: `join()` is an array function, it won't work on a simple object as you try. Read further here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: `item` is a string, so `pairs[item]` is also a string, and strings don't have a `.join` method

Answer (score 1):

The `.join()` method in is an array method. After mapping the string's parts array, join the result back to a string:

```js
function dnaTransform(str) {
  const pairs = {
    A: "T",
    T: "A",
    G: "C",
    C: "G"
  }
  
  return str.split('')
    .map(item => pairs[item])
    .join('')
}

console.log(dnaTransform("ATTGC"))
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this line  `var result = pairs[item].join()`.Here `pairs[item]` will give the value from the object which will be a string but `join` is an array function.

In your case you dont need to `split` & `map`. You can simple loop over the length of the string and retrieve the value from the object and concat with a string variable. Then return that string variable.

```js
const pairs = {
  A: "T",
  T: "A",
  G: "C",
  C: "G"
}

function dnaTransform(str) {
  let finalStr = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    finalStr += pairs[str[i]];
  }
  return finalStr;
}

console.log(dnaTransform("ATTGC"))
```

Comment: Or even `for (const ch of str) { finalStr += pairs[ch]; }` since you're using ES2015+ stuff...